# XmlDocument.SelectNodes returns no nodes for InfoPath XML

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument, infopath2010

I am trying to query an InfoPath XML Document for attachments but the query fails to return any nodes. I don't have much experience working with the XmlDocument class. I believe my issue my be with the namespace. Does anyone have any insight on this.

**Code**

```
// Get the binary stream of the file
Stream formStream = file.OpenBinaryStream();
// Load the stream into an XPathDocument object
XmlDocument ipForm = new XmlDocument();
ipForm.Load(formStream);

//Create a NameSpaceManager object and add the namespace of the form to it
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(ipForm.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("my", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2015-07-13T20:54:32"); //http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2015-07-13T20:54:32 | http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace

  //Get the XML node containing the file attachment
  //XmlNode attachmentNode = ipForm.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Attachments", ns);

 //No nodes returned here 
 XmlNodeList myNodeList = ipForm.SelectNodes("/my:myFields/my:Attachments", ns);
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?mso-infoPathSolution solutionVersion="1.0.0.830" productVersion="14.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="http://sharepoint.calpine.com/sites/dept/fleetsupport/issues/Issues/Forms/template.xsn" name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:Issues:-myXSD-2015-03-30T21-16-50" ?><?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.3"?><?mso-infoPath-file-attachment-present?><my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls" xmlns:ma="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/metadata/properties/metaAttributes" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/dataFields" xmlns:q="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/queryFields" xmlns:dfs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution" xmlns:dms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/documentManagement/types" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" xmlns:s1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ns1="http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2015-03-30T21:16:50" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-us">
<my:InstrumentTag>222</my:InstrumentTag>
<my:IssueDate>2015-07-25</my:IssueDate> 
<my:listName>{B6CDAA90-0F94-4127-A50F-D599952B23CD}</my:listName>
<my:strFormName>TestFormName</my:strFormName>   
<my:Attachments>
    <my:Attachment>/*AttachmentBinary*/</my:Attachment>
</my:Attachments>
<my:Attachments>
    <my:Attachment>/*AttachmentBinary*/</my:Attachment>
</my:Attachments>
```

Comment: Your code and XML are using two different namespaces - 2015-03-30T21:16:50 != 2015-07-13T20:54:32

Comment: should I use 2015-03-30T21:16:50?

Comment: Using that namespace worked. How do I know which namespace to use?

Comment: I suspect that InfoPath is adding a datetime to the XMLNS upon generation.  You might do better using `XmlReader`, or using an `XDocument` looking up with a localname rather than using the namespace prefix.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever your comment was the answer. If you create one, I will mark as solved.

Comment: The problem is - I also share the concerns of the others here - the fact that the namespace ends with a datetime stamp makes me suspicious that it could change again (if it was just a date, that would be somewhat normal to have in a namespace, but the time too?). I'd suggest first confirming whether that namespace uri is stable which is outside my area of expertise. If it's not, I'd suggest you use one of the solutions that uses local names, as bad as that is as a general plan.

Comment: I do not like it either but I believe InfoPath creates this when the form is initially created and it seems to be the only namespace that works for the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication37
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "myFields").Select(y => new
            {
                instrumentTag = y.Elements().Where(z => z.Name.LocalName == "InstrumentTag").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                issueDate = y.Elements().Where(z => z.Name.LocalName == "IssueDate").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                listName = y.Elements().Where(z => z.Name.LocalName == "listName").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                strFormName = y.Elements().Where(z => z.Name.LocalName == "strFormName").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                Attachments = y.Elements().Where(z => z.Name.LocalName == "Attachments").Select(a => new {
                   attachment = a.Elements().Where(b => b.Name.LocalName == "Attachment").Select(c => c.Value).FirstOrDefault()
                }).ToList(),
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is probably better, as long as `XDocument` is an option for him.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that the namespace doesn't mean anything in your case, you can ignore them by using `local-name()` in the XPath, for example :

```
var xpathQuery = "/*[local-name()='myFields']/*[local-name()='Attachments']";
XmlNodeList myNodeList = ipForm.SelectNodes(xpathQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML looks weird.

Why Attachements doesn't not contains the two nodes  ?!

And also, even if I doesn't no really well InfoPath, what is 'myFields' node you're looking for it doesn't seems to exist in your XML sample.

Hope this will help you